# C# XML - Why does this Code keep failing with 0x3A Error?

Tags: c#, xml, linq, soap

i have following code example:

```
PlentySoapRequest_GetAuthentificationToken username = new PlentySoapRequest_GetAuthentificationToken();

        username.Username = user_textbox.ToString();
        username.Userpass = password_textbox.ToString();

        Uri uri = new Uri("http://www.****.de/plenty/api/soap/version105/");


        XNamespace soapenv = @"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/";
        XNamespace xsi = @"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance";
        XNamespace xsd = @"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema";
        XNamespace ver = @"http://www.****.de/plenty/api/soap/version105/";

        var document = new XDocument(
           new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", String.Empty),
           new XElement(soapenv + "Envelope",
               new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "xsi", xsi),
               new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "xsd" , xsd),
               new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "soapenv" , soapenv),
               new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "ver" , ver),
           new XElement(soapenv + "Header"),
           new XElement(soapenv + "Body",
                   new XElement(ver + "GetAuthentificationToken",
                        new XElement("oLogin" + xsi + "type" + ver + "PlentySoapRequest_GetAuthentificationToken",
                            new XAttribute("Username" + xsi + "type" + xsd + "string", username.Username),
                            new XAttribute("Userpass" + xsi + "type" + xsd + "string", username.Userpass)
                           )
                        )
                    )
                )
               );
```

I keep getting the error message in the first line. "plentysoaprequest...."

```
The ':' character, hexadecimal value 0x3A, cannot be included in a name.
```

if I comment out those lines, it keeps say it is in the first line of the code.

**Edit:**
the xml should look like this:

```
<soapenv:Body>
  <ver:GetAuthentificationToken>
     <oLogin xsi:type="ver:PlentySoapRequest_GetAuthentificationToken">
        <!--You may enter the following 2 items in any order-->
        <Username xsi:type="xsd:string">apitest</Username>
        <Userpass xsi:type="xsd:string">apitest</Userpass>
     </oLogin>
  </ver:GetAuthentificationToken>
```

so there seems to be a problem with the xml-sysntax.
I cant figure out how to set **xsi:type** or **xsi:type**

Comment: If the exception is thrown at creating a `PlentySoapRequest_GetAuthentificationToken` object, let us see the constructor code.

Comment: Just to clarify, the **first line** of this code throws an exception? If so, you might want to a) show us the code of the constructor, and b) remove the rest of the code since it's not at issue.

Comment: The string you are passing to the XElement-constructor as "oLogintype" + ver + "PlentySoapRequest_GetAuthentificationToken" would evaluate to this, "oLoginhttp://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instancetypehttp://www.****.de/plenty/api/soap/version105/PlentySoapRequest_GetAuthentificationToken" which is an invalid name.

Comment: It keeps saying, that the problem should be in the first line.
But it isnt.

the xml should look like this:
`<soapenv:Body>
      <ver:GetAuthentificationToken>
         <oLogin xsi:type="ver:PlentySoapRequest_GetAuthentificationToken">
            <!--You may enter the following 2 items in any order-->
            <Username xsi:type="xsd:string">apitest</Username>
            <Userpass xsi:type="xsd:string">apitest</Userpass>
         </oLogin>
      </ver:GetAuthentificationToken>
   </soapenv:Body>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`"oLogin" + xsi + "type"` will create a string with value `"oLoginhttp://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instancetype"`.  That's not a valid name...

You need something a little closer to this:

```
var document = new XDocument(
   new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", String.Empty),
   new XElement(soapenv + "Envelope",
       new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "xsi", xsi),
       new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "xsd", xsd),
       new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "soapenv", soapenv),
       new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "ver", ver),
   new XElement(soapenv + "Header"),
   new XElement(soapenv + "Body",
           new XElement(ver + "GetAuthentificationToken",
                new XElement(xsi + "Login", 
                    new XAttribute(xsi + "type", "blahblah"),
                    new XElement("Username",
                        new XAttribute(xsi + "type", "xsd:string"),
                                "myUserName")
                   )
                )
            )
        )
       );
```

Which generates this XML

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ver="http://www.****.de/plenty/api/soap/version105/">
  <soapenv:Header />
  <soapenv:Body>
    <ver:GetAuthentificationToken>
      <xsi:Login xsi:type="blahblah">
        <Username xsi:type="xsd:string">myUserName</Username>
      </xsi:Login>
    </ver:GetAuthentificationToken>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: His program never gets to this point, though. As he wrote, an exception is thrown at the first line. `I keep getting the error message in the first line.`

Comment: Yeah, I've chosen not to believe that as the error is clearly XML related.  I think 'first line' refers to the `var document = new XDocument ...` section, which is all one 'line' of code in any case.

Comment: Thx this is working, need to ajust it a little bit, but very nice work.